# Spring Neo4j: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, neo4j

I'm having an issue running my Spring Neo4j controller which uses Neo4jTemplate and other custom Repositories. I looked up a few different questions related to this and they didn't resolve the problems - I'll mention some of what I tried later down the post.

I am using Spring Boot to run everything on the server.

The initial error I get trying to run my application is the following:

```
09:07:22.115 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'chatMessageController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate com.ninjasquare.server.controller.node.ChatMessageController.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ninjasquare.server.Application.main(Application.java:19) [NinjaSquareServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [NinjaSquareServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate com.ninjasquare.server.controller.node.ChatMessageController.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
09:07:22.125 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service Tomcat
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ninjasquare.server" />

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.ninjasquare.server.repository"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Cypher query server... -->
    <bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper"
            init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
</bean>

    <beans profile="default">
        <neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/neo4j-db"/>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="prod">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase" id="graphDatabaseService">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://localhost:7474/db/data"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1" value=""/>
            <constructor-arg index="2" value=""/>
        </bean>

        <!--
        Added to allow Controller classes to implement Interfaces. TODO: Need to find out impact of this change
        Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154042/spring-mvc-problem-using-controller-on-controller-implementing-an-interface 
        -->
        <!--  Didn't seem to have made a difference to our issue. Disabling for now -->
        <!--
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
        -->
        <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

Note that  is the same import as in **import com.ninjasquare.server.repository.ChatMessageRepository;**

**chatMessageController.java**

```
package com.ninjasquare.server.controller.node;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.EntityPath;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.ninjasquare.common.communication.model.exception.InvalidPackException;
import com.ninjasquare.common.communication.model.node.chatmessage.ChatMessagePack;
import com.ninjasquare.common.util.Util;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.node.ChatMessage;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.node.ChatStream;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.node.Ninja;
import com.ninjasquare.server.repository.ChatMessageRepository;
import com.ninjasquare.server.repository.ChatStreamRepository;
import com.ninjasquare.server.subsystem.chat.GcmMessagingManager;
import com.ninjasquare.server.subsystem.chat.MessageCache;
import com.ninjasquare.server.subsystem.chat.MessageCacheManager;
import com.ninjasquare.server.subsystem.chat.ProcessMessageCallback;

/**
 * Required functionality of this class:
 * Create Message for a ChatSession (add) - Implemented
 * Retrieve all Messages, greater than a particular time, for a particular ChatSessionId - Implemented
 * @author Dengke
 *
 */
@Controller
public class ChatMessageController extends ProcessMessageCallback {

    @Autowired private Neo4jTemplate template;
@Autowired private ChatMessageRepository chatMessageRepository;
@Autowired @Lazy private ChatStreamRepository chatStreamRepository;

private MessageCacheManager messageCacheManager = new MessageCacheManager(this);

    // Other code ...
}
```

Now one of the things I tried was to add the @Lazy annotation to the repositories to test if everything else worked, and the application would run. However, when I call one of the API URLs I get the NoSuchBeanDefinitionException  error on one of my custom Repository classes (error below):

```
08:54:35.684 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
08:54:35.685 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
08:54:35.802 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 116 ms
Deleting all Ninja.
08:54:35.889 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ninjasquare.server.repository.NinjaRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy(value=true)}] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ninjasquare.server.repository.NinjaRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy(value=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver$1.getTarget(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:82) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:187) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.deleteAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ninjasquare.server.controller.node.NinjaController.deleteAllNinja(NinjaController.java:483) ~[NinjaSquareServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:890) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1033) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar!/:8.0.8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
```

**NinjaRepository.java**

```
package com.ninjasquare.server.repository;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.node.Ninja;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.node.Skill;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.relationship.friend.FriendBlockedByRelationship;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.relationship.friend.FriendBlockedRelationship;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.relationship.friend.FriendDeletedByRelationship;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.relationship.friend.FriendDeletedRelationship;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.relationship.friend.FriendRelationship;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.relationship.friend.FriendRequestRelationship;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.relationship.skill.HasSkillDeletedRelationship;
import com.ninjasquare.server.model.neo4j.relationship.skill.HasSkillRelationship;

@Repository
public interface NinjaRepository extends GraphRepository<Ninja> {

    // Other code ...

}
```

I think these issues may be related. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove the profile / environment section and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the profile / environment section and see if that works.

The template is made available by `Neo4jConfiguration` as part of `<neo4j:config..../>`

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the suggestion. When you say remove the profile/environment section do you mean to remove <beans profile="default"> including removing the inside contents and <beans profile="prod"> including removing the inside contents as well? I tried this and I still get the error: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.